# Is maxoccurs needed for complex types in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

Given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Client>
      <ClientCode>400057</ClientCode>
    <Notes>
      <Note>
        <Text>This is a note</Text>
      </Note>
    </Notes>
  </Client>
  <Client>
      <ClientCode>101134</ClientCode>
    <Notes>
      <Note>
        <Text>This is a note too</Text>
      </Note>
    </Notes>
  </Client>
</Clients>
```

And the Schema XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="Clients">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Client" maxOccurs="3">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ClientCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Notes">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Note" nillable="true">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:sequence>
                                                    <xsd:element name="Text"
                                                        nillable="true"
                                                        type="xsd:string"/>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Does Client require a maxoccurs value to allow more than one client in the XML file. Every validator I can find validates an XML with multiple clients, yet maxoccurs is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There is something missing in your schema; you have defined `Clients` as `<xsd:element name="Clients" />`. It is not typed so it is understated that it can have any content ([xs:anyType](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#key-anyType)). Change it to:

```
<xsd:element name="Clients">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="FileDate"/>
            <xsd:element ref="Client"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and you'll see some errors showing up because validator finds more than one `Client`.

When nothing is specified, it is understood that the attributes `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are set to 1.

To allow several `Client` child elements, you can change your declaration as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="Clients">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="FileDate"/>
            <xsd:element ref="Client" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: I think I may not have phrased the question correctly. This XML passes all validators I can find - I can't figure out why. It allows me to have multiple Client and Note elements in the XML instance document. This does allow this to occur WITHOUT maxOccurs="unbounded". Why?

Comment: So, to be clear, I have removed the items you indicate are missing and it still passes validation. That is what I cannot understand.

Comment: @DanielDevine that's what I explained in the first sentence. `Clients` is defined with `<xsd:element name="Clients" />`, herein you don't specify any particular content model for this tag. Thus it is considered that any/whatever well-formed XML is valid. If you need to constraint the content of `Clients` to only `Client` elements, you **must** define a content model for this element. There you will be able to set min/maxOccurs (amongs other things)

Comment: However, when Note was a simple element in my schema AND I did not specify maxOccurs I did get an error when I had multiple Note elements. When I made it complex, the error disappeared and I never have had Clients defined as a complex type. There will be only one Clients. There will be multiple Client nodes and this is where I noticed that I had not used maxOccurs and yet received no error. If what you write is true I would NEVER receive an invalid state - because as long as it is well formed it will always be valid.  This has not been the empirical case for me.

Comment: So please update your question with the "old" and the "new" content models of `Notes` and `Note` to see what happened. Defining `Note` as a simple or complexType has no incidence on the fact that `Notes` is defined as a sequence of `Note`, with or without maxOccurs.

Comment: When I say "*it is considered that any/whatever well-formed XML is valid*" it is true only for the direct content of `Clients`. If there's a `Client` in it, since this element is defined in the schema, it will be validated against its definition in the schema.

Comment: OK. I have simplified the xml output and the schema and still faced with the same issue. Why no error?

Comment: There's nothing in your schema that tells that `Clients` contains a `FileDate` then `Client` tags. It must have a `complexType` like depicted above. Otherwise, it is considered that any content is allowed. As an input, try to parse and validate `<Clients><hello><world/></hello></Clients>`, it won't show any error either way.

Comment: Except it WILL show an error if I attempt to put two ClientCode elements in one Client. If any content is allowed, why is an error generated when two ClientCode for one client are generated? Is it because the Client element HAS been declared as complex, so that superseded the top level Clients without a definition?

Comment: Of course it will - in the `<xsd:sequence>` you have written `<xsd:element name="ClientCode">` which means that you expect *one* `ClientCode` exactly. If you need more, set a maxOccurs to any number (2, 3, ...) or `unbounded`. The point is that the minOccurs / maxOccurs can only be set on an `<xsd:element>` that is a descendant of a complexType. But you are not allowed to set it on `<xsd:element name="Client">` because this element declaration is a direct child of `<xsd:schema>`.

Comment: OK. I have added back the Notes element and made the top Clients a complex type. Now I have limited Client to 3 occurrences and indeed I can get it to generate an error if I output more than 3 - or any other number I choose. Thank you very much for sticking with this as it evolved.